# How to make custom global command in VS Code terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just installed MongoDB. Instead of writing annoying `cd` to `mongod.exe` every time I want to run MongoDB, I want this file to be available as a global command, so that it runs regardless of the directory I'm in, like `node` or `npm` or `git`. How do I accomplish this for VS Code terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different approaches to start `mongod.exe`:

1. You could add `mongod.exe` to your system's PATH variable (like `git`, `npm` etc.)
2. You could create a script (for example a `.bat`) file in your workspace directory, that contains

   ```bat
   Start "path/to/mongod.exe"
   ```
3. If you want to start the `mongod.exe` via a vscode command like <kbd>Strg</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> for the user settings, you need to write an [extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/overview) and [register a command](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#_commands).

Comment: I saw talks about something called "PATH variable" but I didn't think it's something I need for this. If only they used simpler language to describe things like that... Perfect answer, thank you.